# How to Automatically Print Crystal Reports with Default Printer

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports, ado.net

I'm Having a problem on automatically printing reports using crystal reports. Below is my code snippet

It's Printing but the problem is it ignore the  **ReportView.SelectionFormula** (Which only containing page 1 to Page 10) But printing the all the records in the datasource.

```
 ConnectionInfo ConInfo;
        try
        {
            this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;


            ConInfo = ConfigureCrystalReportsRD();

            ReportDocument.Load(reportToLoad);
            ReportView.ReportSource = ReportDocument;
            SetDBLogonForReportRD(ConInfo, ReportDocument);
            SetReserveFormulaValue();


            string strReportFilter = "";

            strReportFilter = ReportDocument.DataDefinition.RecordSelectionFormula;

            if (strReportFilter != "" && formulaFields != "")
            {
                ReportView.SelectionFormula = strReportFilter + " and " + formulaFields;
            }
            else
            {
                ReportView.SelectionFormula = formulaFields;
            }


            if (isPint == true)
            {
                this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
                System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings printer = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings();
                System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings page = new System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings();
                ReportDocument.PrintToPrinter(printer,page,true);
                MessageBox.Show("Printing at " + printer.PrinterName + " .....");
                this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;

            }

            this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            oGenMethod.ErrorMessage(e.Message, FORMID, "PreviewReport");
        }
```

**Note:**

**ReportView.PrintReport()** does the job successfully but it pops-up the Printer Settings

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:**

What wrong in my code is that i only set the RecordSelectionFormula at ReportViewer Object not on the Report Document.

```
ConnectionInfo ConInfo;

        string strReportFilter = "";

        try
        {
            this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;


            ConInfo = ConfigureCrystalReportsRD();

            ReportDocument.Load(reportToLoad);
            ReportView.ReportSource = ReportDocument;
            SetDBLogonForReportRD(ConInfo, ReportDocument);
            SetReserveFormulaValue();


            strReportFilter = ReportDocument.DataDefinition.RecordSelectionFormula;

            if (strReportFilter != "" && formulaFields != "")
                ReportView.SelectionFormula = strReportFilter + " and " + formulaFields;
            else
                ReportView.SelectionFormula = formulaFields;


            ReportDocument.DataDefinition.RecordSelectionFormula = ReportView.SelectionFormula;




            if (isPint == true)
            {
                this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
                ReportDocument.PrintToPrinter(1, true, 0, 0);
                this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi if you don't want the pop-up to be showed you have to use the PrintToPrinter method of ReportDocument.

so you should do something like this in your code

```
ReportDocument.Load(reportToLoad);
SetDBLogonForReportRD(ConInfo, ReportDocument);
SetReserveFormulaValue();
strReportFilter = ReportDocument.DataDefinition.RecordSelectionFormula;
if (strReportFilter != "" formulaFields != "")
ReportDocument.DataDefinition.RecordSelectionFormula += " and " + formulaFields;
else
ReportDocument.DataDefinition.RecordSelectionFormula = formulaFields;
ReportDocument.PrintToPrinter(1, true, 0, 0);
```

this should solve your problem.

As you asked here is the code I use to test the selection formula and the PrintToPrinter method. First I created a very easy report based on my account table, that I filtered on my code by the code, so that I get one account.

```
var cr = new ReportDocument();
cr.Load(@"c:\Reports\Report1.rpt");
cr.DataDefinition.RecordSelectionFormula = "{Account.Code} = '10000'";
cr.PrintToPrinter(1, true, 0, 0);
```

This code print my report with one record on it, and if i comment the RecordSelectionFormulan line, the report prints the entire account list

Comment: i tried that code but the problem is the formula in ReportView.SelectionFormula is not being applied.

Comment: I updated the example, I had to take away the AND clause in the if because when I tried to save the post it gave me an error.In this way you don't need the report viewer object, you can filter your report and print it directly on default printer

Comment: ReportDocument.PrintToPrinter(1, true, 0, 0); - Yes its printing but printing all pages in the datasource. It ignores the  RecordSelectionFormula

Comment: That sounds strange, I've just tried it on a test project and the data get filtered before the printing. I should see your modified code to see if the problem is there.

Comment: Have you tried to change your code to to '10001' or to the next record? i tried but the problem is it only printing the first page :(

Comment: Yes, I even setted a selection formula on the report and the added a second one from code (like in your example) and it worked fine.

Comment: Got It BRO! I tried to set also the     ReportDocument.DataDefinition.RecordSelectionFormula (The document alone ) and not the Viewer's report formula   (ReportView.SelectionFormula )

thanks for your help bro, it really saves my day! :D

Comment: If you just have to print the report you could remove the ReportView from the page.